# Communication between controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

Angularjs controllers are communicated using Delegates.Other ways to communicate between controller is using service.
I was wondering the exact difference between the use of delegate and service.

Please help!

Comment: Kindly provide 2 examples of  using both the ways..

Comment: Just the concept difference between delegate and service, I wanted to know @anu